# CSS code is not showing on website when i publish it

Tags: android, html, css

I need small clarification if possible, I will just go straight to the point.

So I created a website and i published it on test domain to check if everything is okay.

I opened the site on safari and google chrome on Iphone and everything is perfect.

But when I open that website on android, Samsung Internet Browser and Xiaomi default browser, the site is broken, like in this picture below.

BUT when i opened that exactly site on the first test domain and server on Google Chrome on android its perfect 0.0

So, I published the same website on two different domains. (What happens on first domain i explained above)

The second and third domain are on conpletely different servers and on them everything is okay on all browsers and on all phones.

What should I do ?

Should I start creating new website from 0 again or should I finish the site ?

Anyone had similar problem ?

I do not know what to think, could this be some kind of server problem or domain, I think if the code is bad then it would be bad on all mobile phones, browsers and domains ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfEpZ.jpg)   (Image of the problem)

Tried on two other domains if the website is working and it does, but I still have some questions.

Comment: Please post the code that causes your problem, and explain exactly what is going wrong. Also try to find error messages in the developer tools.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This can be caused by server cache. Have you tried to clear the cache of the server or maybe rebooting it ?